# Google Sheets - shift the cell value according to the name beside the cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Problem**: The details of item can't move together when latest stock update.

The picture below shows the initial input:

[image]

The picture below shows the problem when the stock changes:

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

The formula of Name column for repeat the item:

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT($AL11:$AL13&"@",$AM11:$AM13),"@"))),"where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: Do you enter data in `Details` column manually?

Comment: Yes, so I actually curious can I shift the details data like that

Comment: What if you change the stock to a smaller value for example you change watermelon from 4 to 3, is it supposed to clear the last row (Watermelon, 11kg)?

Comment: Yes, but the last row Watermelon will delete only, due to I insert the 11kg manually so it will still stay at the same spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

**Using apps script**

Not sure if it is possible using formula, but here's a script you can use. This of course still needs some tweaking to align with your spreadsheet.

Also what I've done with the script is it deletes both the last name and detail if you change it to lower stock since it makes more sense rather than keeping it in same spot.

**try:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  if(range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 2);
    const dataValues = removeEmptyRows(dataRange.getValues());
    const outputRange = dataRange.offset(0, 2);
    const outputData = removeEmptyRows(outputRange.getValues());

    let output = [];

    dataValues.filter(x => x[1] && x[1] > 0).forEach(row => {
      const [fruit, count] = row;
      let currentFruit = outputData.filter(x => x[0] == fruit);
      let currentCount = currentFruit.length, rows;

      if(currentCount < count) {
        rows = count - currentCount;
        currentFruit.push(...Array(rows).fill([fruit, '']));
      }
      else if(count < currentCount) {
        rows = currentCount - count;
        currentFruit = currentFruit.slice(0, -1 * rows);
      }
      output.push(...currentFruit);
    });

    outputRange.clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(2, 3, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}

function removeEmptyRows(array) {
  return array.filter(x => x.filter(String).length > 0)
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Let me know if this works or if you have other questions.

### EDIT - Modified code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  if(range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    // Needed values to modify
    // Input: Data that holds how many items are in each category
    const inputRowStart = 2;  // Input starts at:
    const inputColStart = 1;  // ROW 2, COL 1 (A2)
    // Output: Data where the output is written 
    const outputRowStart = 2; // Output starts at:
    const outputColStart = 3; // ROW 2, COL 3 (C2)
    const outputCols = 3;     // 3 COLS (Fruits, Details, Date)

    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const inputRange = sheet.getRange(inputRowStart, inputColStart, lastRow - 1, 2);
    const inputValues = removeEmptyRows(inputRange.getValues());
    const outputRange = sheet.getRange(outputRowStart, outputColStart, lastRow - 1, outputCols);
    const outputData = removeEmptyRows(outputRange.getValues());

    let output = [];

    inputValues.filter(row => row[1] > 0).forEach(row => {
      const [fruit, count] = row;
      let currentFruit = outputData.filter(row => row[0] == fruit);
      let currentCount = currentFruit.length, rows;

      if(currentCount < count) {
        rows = count - currentCount;
        currentFruit.push(...Array(rows).fill([fruit, ...Array(outputCols - 1).fill('')]));
      }
      else if(count < currentCount) {
        currentFruit = currentFruit.slice(0, count);
      }
      output.push(...currentFruit);
    });

    outputRange.clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(outputRowStart, outputColStart, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
}

function removeEmptyRows(array) {
  return array.filter(row => row.filter(String).length > 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes right there, the coding is working but I wanna ask what code should I change if I add others details beside the Details column? For example, I add date beside the details column, then the datetime should also follow the details move up and down

Comment: @JunJieOng I have added modified code in the posted answer. This is more flexible and easier to adjust. I have also added comments to easily identify which parts you need to change.